# How to link external CSS and Script (assets) in Laravel 5.1 project

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

Hi guys am new to Laravel and this is my first project to do in laravel, I had trouble linking my assets(CSS & Js) file on my views.. I did a research an found if I will use `{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}` in Laravel 5.1 it will work. I did succeed when it was just a single link, but when I add other links..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/animate.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/plugins/parallax-slider/css/parallax-slider.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/custom.css')}}">
```

The server denied the access to all files in assets folder `Access forbidden!`.
My .htaccess file code is..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Question is if .htaccess file had a problem why when I put one asset link it accept?
Or what is the proper way of linking the files?
Am using XAMPP as my local server.
*Guy I just learned Laravel yesterday so be easy on me... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for a help I did solve my problem.

1. I went again at `http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset`

   - there I found they say `$url = asset('img/photo.jpg');` will give me the url to my asset file.
2. So I Route...

   ```
   Route::get('check', function () {

   $url = asset('assets/css/headers/header-default.css');

   return $url;
   });
   ```

   I got the link `http://localhost/Dentist/public/assets/css/headers/header-default.css`
3. So i just violate the rule if there was any and I did this in my stylesheet.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $url = asset('assets/css/style.css'); ?>">`

--> ** Apart from that you can do this **

```
{!!asset('assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js')!!}
```

because as the said if you use blade, then there is no need of using `<?php echo ; ?>` command... so I replaced `<?php echo $url = ; ?>` with `{!! asset('assets/css/...') !!}`
Make sure your files are in `public/assets/` directory

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

You can use laravel blade template method

```
{!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}

{!! HTML::script('js/script.js') !!}
```

Note :you should add css files into public folder means in my example it will be like `public/css` folder.
same will be applied to jquery files also.

also you can add following way if you are using online links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or else

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this and replace css with your folder name.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/home.css')}}">
```

Comment: I tried that method yesterday and it didn't help... I replaced all my previous link with what you suggested by it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried without escaping the string it worked.. Thanks `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!!asset('css/home.css')!!}">`

Comment: Cool, it does not matter if you use `<?php ?>` tags with blade, it should still work, in fact your original post did work on my project. Did you have your assets folder in public folder? or was it pointing to the assets folder in resources folder?

Comment: I placed my assets folder on `public` directory.. just as what they say... Thanks for reaching back....@mdamia

Answer (score 1):

When adding assets it's best to use assets helper **`http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls`**

For external

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

and also laravel ships with an htaccess file try replace it with yours https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Also give correct permissions to your directories

```
Folders 755

Files 644

Apart from;

app/storage 777 (or 755 with owner as webserver user)
```

Comment: the htacces file am using came with Laravel 5.1 it self, I tried to compaire with the one you suggested they were the same and even when I replace the still it didn't solve the problem. I put my css file in one folder called **assets** inside Laravel **Public** folder..

Comment: @Josh407 please check your directory & file permissions.

Comment: I changed permission and put full control but it didn't help... though I find a shortcut on how to solve the problem and I just posted it below. please check and give me your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [Laravel Collective HTML Package](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html)

After installed this package you can use like this

```
{!! Html::style('your/css/file.css') !!}
{!! Html::script('your/js/file.js') !!}
{!! Html::image('your/image/file.jpg') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case me looked  upper of the place dropped the error.
I found me has missed a " ' " character in a same looked declaration:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js)}}"></script>
```

somewhere up there.
 As you can see there  missed character " ' " after ".js"
So that all underneath declarations havent  "  '  " pair until this error place